# Eclipse config locations on linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, centos, centos7

I'm using eclipse Mars.1 JEE with CDT on CentOS 7 Gnome Classic and I'm wondering where eclipse saves configs and plugins. The reason is that I had the following problem and I'd like to understand.

I installed a plugin to apply external themes (Eclipse Colo Theme) and I changed the colors. I didn't like the plugin and removed it but I didn't set the colors back. After some time I found code snippets which where not readable because of the colors. But I forgot about the plugin and the changes I applied. I tried to solve the problem and looked for a solution but I found no solution. I downloaded eclipse, extracted it in the downloads folder and started it. The problem was there, too. And also my proxy configs. So I installed the plugin, reverted my changes and checked both eclipse folders. Both versions were fixed. So both versions check a central location on my system for configs, themes and plugins.

I found ~/.eclipse but it doesn't seem like there is a config. Are there other places were eclipse saves a config, even when I use a portable eclipse version?

Comment: Most preferences are stored in the subfolder `.metadata` of the _workspace_. If you switch to another _workspace_ (_File > Switch Workspace > ..._) you will see, which preferences are workspace specific and which are not.

Comment: I changed the workspace and the themes changed too. So the theme is saved in the workspace. Thanks

Comment: Great. I converted my comment to an answer (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Most preferences** like theme, color and fonts, etc. **are stored in the subfolder `.metadata` of the workspace**.

If you switch to another workspace (*File > Switch Workspace > ...*) you will see, which preferences are workspace specific and which are not.

In some cases, the ***Restore Defaults*** button in the *Preferences* dialog (e. g. in ***Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts***) can be used to restore the default preferences.